# MySQL Group by and Order

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to group messages like conversation and to display only the latest message from a conversation, therefore I need the one with the highest number in the column `time`.

This is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM console_msgs 
WHERE `to` = $user[id] 
GROUP BY `from` 
ORDER BY time DESC
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you post/include your table structure so that everyone can see the table(s) involved.

Comment: We may need your schema definition, plus some sample data and results.  Don't ever just use `SELECT *` - always explicitly define your desired results.  Avoid the use of reserved words when naming things - `from` could probably be renamed to `sentBy` or something.  Don't unnecessarily abbreviate, it just makes it harder to read.  Don't name columns after their type, name them after what they represent - ie does `time` represent `sentAt` or `receivedAt`?  Please be aware that, although legal in mySQL, choosing non-aggregate column when using a `GROUP BY` have 'random' values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html):

```
SELECT console_msgs.*
FROM   console_msgs NATURAL JOIN (
         SELECT   MAX(time) AS time
         FROM     console_msgs
         WHERE    `to` = $user[id]
         GROUP BY `from`
       ) t
WHERE  `to` = $user[id]
```

Comment: Getting this error: Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the result set you need returned but I think you need to use the LIMIT keyword to only return the top result. Give this a try:

```
SELECT from, MAX(time) 
FROM console_msgs 
WHERE `to` = $user[id] 
GROUP BY `from` 
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the latest message from *each* sender, not just the latest message overall (which your answer may not even do, as the `time` values selected are indeterminate).

Answer (score 0):

You won't want to use `GROUP BY` to achieve what I think you're asking.  You just want multiple order bys

```
SELECT * 
FROM console_msgs 
WHERE `to` = $user[id] 
ORDER BY `from`, time DESC
```